# beautifulsoup print no results

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Hello I am not sure what I am doing wrong. the code runs without errors but 0 results. Any way to test what is pulling?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.expedia.com/carsearch?locn=Orlando+%28MCO+-+Orlando+Intl.%29&loc2=&date1=4%2F24%2F2022&date2=4%2F30%2F2022&d1=2022-04-24&d2=2022-04-30&aarpcr=off&vend=&pickupIATACode=MCO&dpln=5194573&returnIATACode=&drid1=&time1=1030AM&time2=1030AM&olat=&olon=&dlat=&dlon=&dagv=1&subm=1&fdrp=0&ttyp=2&acop=2&rdus=10&rdct=1&styp=4"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="app-bernie-cars-shopping-web") 


job_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="offer-cards-list")


for job_element in job_elements:
    title_element = job_element.find("div", class_="title-container")
    print(title_element.text.strip())
```

the expected result should be the title of the car (in my case Midsize SUV) also how do I add the result to a pandas data frame?

Comment: [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If you try breaking it down line by line, you'll be able to see what each step pulls, if that's what you mean? Doing that and printing results (print(results)), it looks as though there are no class_="offer-cards-list" objects within id="app-bernie-cars-shopping.

Comment: @bensonium its weird when I tried the see the main Id it was below app-bernie. Looking into more deeply I tried results = soup.find(id="offer-cards-list") to see but it returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify' but in the inspect section is <div id ="offer-card-list">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

**First**, to test this I would see what exactly is being returned to 'job_elements'. You could do this by printing that to console or using your IDE's debug mode and setting a break near that line.

**Second**, I looked through the HTML of the site and  it looks like a better spot to run find_all is class="offer-card-desktop" because these are the actual elements of the ordered list that is created.

```
job_elements = results.find_all("li", class_="offer-card-desktop")
```

This way you could return the list items of the OL to job_elements and then pick out what you need from the divs returned.

**Finally**, I don't see a "title-container" class anywhere in the div, but if youre looking for the Title of the car that's given on the card, what you could do is:

```
for result in results.find_all("div", class_="uitk-layout-grid flex-container") 
    print(result.get_text())
```

I'm unable to test this at this time, but I hope this gives you a few ideas to move forward. Best of luck!

Comment: THANK YOU! you pointed me in the right direction! really appreciated